# NineOldAndroids ObjectAnimators don't work with ProGuard and signed apk

Tags: android, proguard, nineoldandroids

I am using NineOldAndroids' ObjectAnimators to fade in Android Map v2 markers with the following code:

```
mMarkerSelected = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(location.getLatLng())
        .title(location.getName())
        .snippet(location.getId())
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(location.getMarkerHue())));
mMarkerSelected.setAlpha(0.0f);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mMarkerSelected, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.f)
                .setDuration(300).start();
```

This works perfectly with debuggable versions of the apk.

However, when I sign my apk and use ProGuard, suddenly marker doesn't fade in. My guess is that the alpha attribute has been obfuscated so that passing `"alpha"` into `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` doesn't match up with the obfuscated alpha attribute of the `Marker`. How can I get the animation to work when using ProGuard?

Just for completeness, this is the only contents of my proguard-rules.txt

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It uses reflection so you need your method names intact *i.e. setAlpha()*, something like this in your proguard config:

```
 # This is due to ObjectAnimator using reflection to access get/sets
 -keep class com.your.package.ClassThatUsesObjectAnimator { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with `-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker { *; }`. Can you update the answer, or should I instead keep my personal class that uses ObjectAnimator?

Comment: You can do either, personally I would have a class to control the animation but not proguarding the marker is also fine

Answer (score 2):

Nineolddroids library is open sourced already so running proguard on it is pointless.

If you have a choice between obfuscating your own source file or a 3rd party open sourced library it would be wise to choose your own source file.

Add these lines to your `proguard-project.txt` and your application will work fine.

```
## Nineolddroid related classes to ignore

-keep class com.nineoldandroids.animation.** { *; }
-keep interface com.nineoldandroids.animation.** { *; }
-keep class com.nineoldandroids.view.** { *; }
-keep interface com.nineoldandroids.view.** { *; }
```